# Is there any good angular js walk through libraries to walk through the whole application?

Tags: angularjs, walkthrough

I'm building an online app with angular js. Is there any libraries that can do the walk through for my application. I know some javascript libraries such as intro.js, Bootstro.js. But they all depend on jquery. Is there any angular based walkthrough javascript libraries? angular-intro maybe one example. But I got the injection error not knowing the reason. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know of one.

**ngOnboarding** - https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngOnboarding

You can write wrapper around existing javascript/jquery on-boarding libraries like you mentioned intro.js or Bootstro.js.